# (why) is this ratio the golden ratio?

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, ratio, golden-ratio

Looking at a slight variation of the fibonacci sequence
f(x) = f(x-1) + f(x-2) + 1 
 where f(1) = 1, f(2) = 1 
 
I'm trying to find the ratio of this sequence but can't figure out how. To get an approximation I just tried looking at some random examples, (i.e. f(10)/f(9), f(20)/f(19)) 
And it seems that this is the golden ratio, but I can't understand how that is correct as this sequence seems to grow much faster than the fibonacci sequence

Comment: We can tell that *if* this modification of the Fibonacci sequence tends to a geometric sequence (as the Fibonacci sequence itself does), then the common ratio must also be $\varphi$, since if we divide by $f(x-2)$ and take the limit, we get $r^2 = r + 1$ (since $1/f(x-2) \to 0$), which is the same characteristic equation as the Fibonacci series has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write $g(x)= f(x)+1$ you got $$g(x+1)=g(x)+g(x-1)$$